# References for hyperfinite factors

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Can  I have references of hyperfine  $II_1$ factors where I can get structural properties to be studied and more characterizations.

Comment: If you do not indicate your background level of knowledge it is hard to recommend an *appropriate* source. After all, sources are only useful if you can follow what they are saying

Comment: I am beginner, recommend according to that. I only know some basic on the von Neumann algebras@ Yemon choi

Comment: Google can be your friend: http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/gaboriau/evenements/IHP-trimester/IHP-CIRM/Notes=Cyril=finite-vonNeumann.pdf

Comment: Also, Sinclair and Smith's book is (very) nice, I think: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Neumann-Algebras-Mathematical-Society-Lecture/dp/0521719194

Comment: You should have a look to the book *An introduction to II1 factors*  by Claire Anantharaman and Sorin Popa: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~popa/Books/IIun-v13.pdf